# Check that string is in IPv6 multicast IP format

Tags: c#, ipv6

Is there any way to check that a string is in a IPv6 multicast IP format ? I know that how I can check the format of a unicast address for eg. 192.45.2.133 but want to know about IPv6 multicast address checking

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1705/IP-Multicasting-in-C this may be helpful

Answer (score 3):

Parse it into an [`IPAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object and then check the [`IsIP6Multicast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.isipv6multicast%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

```
var ipString = "...";
var address = IPAddress.Parse(ipString);
var isIP6Multicast = address.isIP6Multicast;
```

(If you're not sure that it's even an IP address, then use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) first)

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address).

> Multicast addresses in IPv6 have the prefix ff00::/8.

```
General multicast address format
Bits    8       4       4       112
Field   prefix  flags   scope   group ID
The prefix holds the binary value 11111111 for any multicast address. 
...
```

So that I think you can check if the IPV6 IP string start with `0xff`.